WooCommerce - How to get custom attribute label and use it in function
I have created the following code to get the attribute value of a custom attribute named Model and display it in a div table. I am lost on how to get the proper label in there instead of the static text that I am using right now. I created a shortcode to be used on my site where I want it and added some conditions whether to display it or not when the attribute is empty. In the final version there will be more attributes; for this question, I kept it at one.
add_shortcode( 'display-attributes-algemeen', 'get_product_attributes_shortcode' );
function get_product_attributes_shortcode( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'id'    => get_the_ID(),
    ), $atts, 'display-attributes-algemeen' ) );

    global $product;

    if ( ! is_a($product, 'WC_Product') ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( $id );
    }

    if ( is_a($product, 'WC_Product') ) {
        $model = $product->get_attribute('Model');

    if ( $model ) {
   $output = '<span class="specstitel">Algemeen</span><div class="divTableAtt LichtBlauweRegels">
   <div class="divTableAttBody">';
            
            if ( $model ) {
                $output .= '<div class="divTableAttRow">
                <div class="divTableAttCell">Model</div>
                <div class="divTableAttCell">' . $model . '</div>
                </div>';
            }

   return $output . '</div></div>';
            
        }
    }
}

I was looking into either wc_attribute_label() or get_taxonomy() but for both I am lost on how to implement it.
EDIT:
if ( is_a($product, 'WC_Product') ) {
$model = $product->get_attribute('Model');
$model_label = wc_attribute_label('pa_model'); 

and further up I added:
if ( $model ) { 
$output .= '<div class="divTableAttRow">
<div class="divTableAttCell">' . $model_label . '</div>
<div class="divTableAttCell">' . $model . '</div> </div>';

I added this in the code and now all labels are being displayed as they should.

The attribute should be pa_model instead of just Model.

The current code works, I only need to get the labels as well.

$attribute_label = wc_attribute_label( $attribute_name ); where $attribute_name should be pa_model not just model

So i tried adding:
if ( is_a($product, 'WC_Product') ) {
$model = $product->get_attribute('Model');
$model_label = $product->wc_attribute_label('pa_model');
and further up I added:
if ( $model ) {
$output .= '
' . $model_label . '
' . $model . '
';
But that doesn't work.
I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Where are you trying to output this shortcode? On a single product page? Since get_the_ID() will return the product ID only if you are on a single product page. Also $id is not defined should be $id = $atts['id'];

It is on a single product page.
https://shop.r-go-tools.nl/ergonomische-documenthouder/r-go-flex-read-documenthouder/
If you scroll down a little bit and click on "Details en Specificaties" you will see the output (I changed it back to original, cause it broke my site).

It is on a single product page indeed.
The code from the first post is what I use right now and it works for all the values. I am learning this on the go.
I really appreciate your feedback.

I just see now that my code is not per line, but compressed in my remark... hard to see that I did. I will add the code to the original post.

I got it to work!!!
Thanks @Snuffy for pointing me to the right direction.
